# Permissions for an item - Role inheritance - Coveo search - Missing results

Tags: coveo

I am struggling with an issue in refining the `Coveo` search results in a `Sitecore 9.3` solution. The problem I am facing is that there are specific items, that I can access just fine in the live websites, but `Coveo` does not return those in the result set, because of the way permissions are handled.

Now, I am not saying that the problem is on the `Coveo` side, but I am trying to figure out what might be wrong with our solution.

The scenario is the following:

1. We have a page on our website called **Page 1** for example
2. We set the permissions for that page to be as follows: **Role 1** - *allow*, **Role 2** - *allow*, **Role 3** - *deny* (in the inheritance section).
3. **Role 1** and **Role 2** are members of **Role 3**, as set in Sitecore (all of our roles are set up like this).
4. The way it works for us is that it denies access to all users that have the **Role 3** assigned, except for the ones that have ones of the roles **Role 1** / **Role 2** (so it's sort of like we deny everyone until a specific role that allows access)

Initially, I thought that maybe we have some processor that would handle this behavior in a different way, but I could not find any.

I understand that **Deny** overrules **Allow**, but I was wondering what is the behavior that should be when the **Allowed** roles are actually members of the **Deny** role.

Could anyone help with at least a suggestion? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, it seems that the actual problem was the fact that **Role 3** was also assigned to the logged in user (as an individual role), so in this case the inheritance breaking was not working. That is how the solution was implemented from the beginning, but only now it started to actually hit us in the face.

After removing **Role 3** from the logged in users, everything was fine.